# Extract a part of duration from alog file

Tags: excel

I have a log file as the below :

```
USER_NAME   STARTTIME   ENDTIME         STATUS  DURATION    

V15AEMBABY1 8:19:53 AM  2/12/2017 8:20  IN      19  

V15AEMBABY1 8:20:12 AM  2/12/2017 8:46  out     1550    

V15AEMBABY1 8:46:02 AM  2/12/2017 8:46  IN      18  

V15AEMBABY1 8:46:20 AM  2/12/2017 8:48  IN      139

V15AEMBABY1 8:48:39 AM  2/12/2017 8:48  IN      5   

V15AEMBABY1 8:48:44 AM  2/12/2017 8:49  IN      75  

V15AEMBABY1 8:49:59 AM  2/12/2017 8:51  IN      109 

V15AEMBABY1 8:51:48 AM  2/12/2017 8:51  IN      5   

V15AEMBABY1 8:51:53 AM  2/12/2017 8:54  IN      133

V15AEMBABY1 8:54:06 AM  2/12/2017 8:54  IN      0   

V15AEMBABY1 8:55:37 AM  2/12/2017 8:55  IN      7   

V15AEMBABY1 8:55:44 AM  2/12/2017 9:03  IN      460 

V15AEMBABY1 9:03:24 AM  2/12/2017 9:04  IN      51
```

I need to know the `Sum` of the `IN` durations for the username: `V15AEMBABY1` from `8:45:00 AM` till `09:00:00`

Comment: Use the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B).

Answer (score 0):

Both methods below assume your data (above) is in cells `A1:E14` (inc. headings)

## Method 1

Use a `SUMIFS` function (recommended)

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E14,A2:A14,"V15AEMBABY1",D2:D14,"IN",B2:B14,">08:30",C2:C14,"<02/12/2017  09:00")
```

## Method 2

It's old school, but you might like this method because it's more visual. Place your criteria (below) into cells `H1:K2`, you can change them as you like

```
USER_NAME        STARTTIME      ENDTIME                 STATUS
V15AEMBABY1      >08:30         <02/12/2017  09:00      IN
```

Then anywhere else, place the following formula:

```
=DSUM($A$1:$E$14,"DURATION",$H$1:$K$2)
```

It's important you include your headings here - hence the use of `$A$1:$E$14` rather than `$A$2:$E$14`